# Ruby on Rails problem: in `match?': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new on Ruby on Rails. I have installed ruby and rails, but when I create a new project with command: "rails new myapp" during downloading packages I see this problem:
"run  bundle install
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/pathname.rb:50:in `match?': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)".

Can you help me with this issue, please?

Answer (score -1):

So, I've reinstalled ruby from 3.1.x to 2.7.x and it works